# rust std::path::Path is_file() always returns false

Tags: rust

I just started using rust, and i'm having trouble finding out if a path is a file or directory. I have this function that gets input, which i'm using to get the path:

```
pub fn input(msg: &str, v: &mut String) {
  println!("{}", msg);
  stdin().read_line(v).unwrap();
}
```

When i take input like this:

```
let mut path = String::new();
input("What is the path to your file/directory?", &mut path);
```

The I try to make a Path with it, and check if it's a file:

```
let file = Path::new(&path);
println!("{}", file.is_file());
```

Which prints `false`

When I make the Path from a set String, it works:

```
let file = Path::new("../directory/file.js");
println!("{}", file.is_file());
```

Prints `true`

I'm sure that i'm giving it a valid file path in the input function. I've read the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.is_file) to try to find what i'm doing wrong but I can't

Any idea whats wrong here?

Comment: From the top of my head: Does `input()` include the newline-character? `is_file()` may return `false` as `...\n` can't be found.

Comment: Not sure, i'll check and get back to you

Comment: Yup, i'm currently changing the `input()` function to return a trimmed version of the input

Comment: Alright it works, thanks! instead of changing the `input()` i added this line: `path = path.trim().to_string();`